# loop through component based on number in select list - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops

In my App component, I have a component which returns a select list with 15 option with the numbers 1 to 15. I also have an onChange on the select list which stores the selected number in the App state.

My goal is that when the user selects a number from the select list It'll loop through that number and output a new component that just returns a text input (for example if 9 is chosen, automatically you see 9 input fields). Eventually, the value from each text input will be saved into an array in the App state.

My App.js

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <Location change={this.changeLocation} value={this.state.location} />
      <Date changeDate={this.handleDate} value={this.state.date} />
      <NumOfTunes
        handleChange={this.handleNumOfTunes}
        value={this.state.numberOfTunes}
      />
      <button type="submit">Generate SetList</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleReset}>
        Reset
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
);
```

My select list component

```
const numOfTunes = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={props.handleChange}>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you post your current code

Comment: Please post you code on codeSandbox

Comment: const returnInputs = ()=>{
   for(let i=0; i< selectedNumber; i++){
      return <input onChange={(value)=>{setValues[...values, value]}/>
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
const returnInputs (){
   for(let i=0; i< selectedNumber; i++){
      return <input key={i} value={this.state.inputValues[i]} onChange={this.addInputsToList}/>
   }
}

const addInputsToList (e) {
   setState({
    inputValues: [...this.state.inputValues, e.target.value]
   })
}


render(){
   ....
   {this.renderInputs()}
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store an `inputCount` in your state (updated when `onChange` is fired) and use that value to create your input list component:

```js
 class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputCount: 0
    };

    this.onSelectChange = this.onSelectChange.bind(this);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div style={containerStyles}>
        <select onChange={this.onSelectChange}>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
        {this.state.inputCount > 0 &&
        <div style={inputContainer}>
          {[...Array(Number(this.state.inputCount)).keys() ]
          .map(el =>
            <input value="" />
          )}
        </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }

  onSelectChange(e) {
    this.setState(
      ({ inputCount: e.target.value })
    );
  }
}

const containerStyles = {
  display: "block",
  justifyContent: "center",
  flexWrap: "wrap"
};

const inputContainer = {
 display: "flex",
 padding: '1rem',
 flexDirection: "column",
  fontSize: "30px",
  color: "#eec200"
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <Button />,
    document.body
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```